# Unity2D character moving with jitters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I created codes to move my character with Rigidbody2D.
I was able to move around fine with transform.position, but whenever i use the rigibody2d, it is causing lots of jitters.  Please help!  Alos, let me know if you need more info.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainCharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 10f;
public float psi = 10f;Vector2 lastClickedPos;
bool moving;
private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
private Vector2 position;

private void Awake()
{
    rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    position = rb2D.position;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);            
    }
    rb2D.MovePosition(Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, position, Time.deltaTime * speed));
}

public void MakingStoneTools()
{
    Debug.Log("creating sharp stone");
    psi = psi - 2;
    Debug.Log("Psi:" + psi);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the code inside **Update** to **FixedUpdate**. This is because how the physics system works.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);            
    }
    rb2D.MovePosition(Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, position, Time.deltaTime * speed));
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the comment.  FixedUpdate creates a delay on the movement when I click.  Meaning the clicks will not respond every now and then.

Comment: You’re right, checking input in FixedUpdate can miss something. You could put “if input, bool = true” in Update() and “if bool, bool = false and move” in FixedUpdate().